# Repeat each row n times (with random numbers intact) in google sheets

Tags: arrays, function, google-sheets, random, flatten

My goal is to generate 10 random phone numbers for each area code:

[image: data]

In cell B3 I have the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUND(RANDARRAY(4,7)*9))
```

which is responsible for generating 7 numbers (excluding area code) between 0 and 9  for each row.

The full phone number should have 10 numbers in total (including area code)

I also want to concatenate each area code with the 7 random numbers and repeat each full number (which would be in one cell now) 10 times (10 random numbers for code 111, etc...).

I want the RANDARRAY function to stay dynamic while repeating I don't want to repeat a static number.

Any idea on how this might be done?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: Sure just one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN("("&A3:A6&")-"&REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(
 RANDARRAY(4, 3)*10^20, "0"), "\d{7}")))
```

[image]

with secondary dash:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN("("&A3:A6&")-"&REGEXEXTRACT(TEXT(
 RANDARRAY(4, 10)*10^20, "0"), "\d{7}")), "(.+-\d{3})(\d{4}$)", "$1-$2"))
```